# Encode an array into non-array JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I encode an array like this:

```
$myArray = "["user1","user2","user3"]"
```

into this dynamically:

```
{
"myArray": "user1, user2, user3"
}
```

I understand that the JSON above isn't an array but I still want it in that form. Also, JSON encode doesn't encode it exactly like how I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to use the array and get a "non-array" in JSON as you show, you need to `impode()` and get the `myArray` as a key:

```
$myArray = ["user1","user2","user3"];

$myArray = implode(', ', $myArray);
echo json_encode(compact('myArray'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Alternately:

```
echo json_encode(['myArray' => implode(', ', $myArray)], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Both yield:

```
{
    "myArray": "user1, user2, user3"
}
```

This is just really a one element array with a comma separated list as the data.